# How to erase/clear a path in Android canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, android-view

I am making a drawing app with erase/undo/redo functions.
After adding undo/redo functions, eraser just paints a black path.
Each time a path is drawn (on MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) Iadd the paths to a linkedlist. If eraseMode is on, I put the color as -1 so that I can handle  it in onDraw.

```
private void touch_up() {
    drawPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);

    if(!eraseMode) {
        pathColor.put(drawPath, paintColor);
        paths.add(drawPath);
    }
    else {
        pathColor.put(drawPath, -1);
        paths.add(drawPath);
    }
    drawPath = new Path(); // new obj or drawPath.reset();
}
```

Then on onDraw, I loop through the paths list and draw the paths onto the canvas

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++) {
            if(pathColor.get(paths.get(i)) != -1)
            {
                drawPaint.setColor(pathColor.get(paths.get(i)));
                canvas.drawPath(paths.get(i), drawPaint);
            }
            else
            {
                drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
                canvas.drawPath(paths.get(i), drawPaint);
            }
            drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
        }
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
}
```

But all the erased lines are black.

Why does the following draw a black line

```
drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
canvas.drawPath(somePath, drawPaint);
```

Why cant I just draw a path with eraser mode?
Why does eraser work if take out the for loop in onDraw method (as below)?

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);        
    canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
}
```

I dont want to use background color as eraser as I will have to paint on images.

Please help me implement a simple eraser.

Many thanks

Comment: If you're saving the paths in a List, why don't you just remove them from the List to undo, instead of trying to draw new paths over them? The removed paths can be added to another List to keep track of the redos.

Comment: check this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54105#c1